# If gate to source is breakdown of P-Channel MOSFET, Will gate to drain be also breakdown?

Tags: mosfet, dielectric-breakdown

I have failured P channel MOSFETs.

During dielectric test or ESD test, MOSFET died.

Max. Gate to sorce voltage is only 8V. There is no protection for gate to source.

Gate to drain shorted. Also gate to sorce shorted.

I don't know the process of breakdown.

Firstly, is gate to sorce breakdown? And then gate to drain will also be breakdown?

Or if gate to source shorted. Is resiatance between gate to drain almost zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is protection. If the parts are cheap maybe you can sacrifice one by characterizing I vs. V of G-S voltage. There may be a ~9-10V Zener in there.

Another way to tell is the relatively large *typical* (not maximum) gate leakage current.

In any case, it sounds like you basically melted the chip. The default state of destroyed semiconductors is generally a conductive blob. If you pass massive amounts of current the bonding wires or chip will go open, but shorted is how they like to perish.